# Angular Frontend display Laravel backend stored image

Tags: angular, laravel, image, variables, ngfor

I want to display image in frontend (Angular).But that image stored in Laravel(5.5) backend.I already try.What should i do?
[image]

This is error 
[image]

Comment: What is the url of the laravel backend?

Comment: backend/public/admin//images/uploads/image.extention     this is the path.

Comment: laravel url http://localhost:8000

Comment: @RuwanthaSameera As per the console log you are missing the file extension. Seems `beer.image` doesn't include extension.

Comment: if your backend url is localhost:8000, then images will be at localhost:8000/admin/images/uploads

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam oh.i forget that.thank you

Comment: @Smalbil yes.thats the problem i faced

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam i updated it.but still have the same problem.any suggessions?

Comment: if you type the full url to the picture in your browser..so the localhost:8000/etc/etc, can you then see it? If you can not, then you might have to check if you have symlinked the storage directory correctly. If you can, then it is angular syntax problems. Because I can clearly see {{beer.slug}} within a string. So maybe src="localhost:8000/admin/images/uploads/"+{{beer.slug}}  or something like that.

Comment: @Smalbil its not working :(

Comment: Maybe something stupid, but is it the extension .jpeg or .jpg. Can you open the image when you just copy the url and open it in a different browser tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image stored in Storage folder of Laravel.Then create this route in route route.php (if your using above Laravel 5.4, in web.php)

```
Route::get('images/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $file = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::get($filename);
    return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
});
```

Now you can load your image using this route like this.

```
<img src="websiteurl/images/filename.jpg"/>
```

If image stored in public folder, you can load it directly

```
   <img src="websiteurl/admin/images/uploads/filename.jpg"/>
```

> You need to run both of your Laravel(Backend) and Angular(Frontend) Application same time (based on your code)

Answer (score 0):

The `storage_path()`

function returns the fully qualified path to the storage directory:

```
$path = storage_path();
```

Then:

```
<img src="{{$path}}/{{beer.image}}.ext">
```

or

```
<img src="{{storage_path()}}/{{beer.image}}.ext">
```

Is probably better practice. You also need the file extension.